# Embeddable is null so auditing does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following embeddable

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class BaseEntity {
  
  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "created_date")
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

Which I embedded into another entity like this

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "room")
@Builder
public class room {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  @Embedded
  private BaseEntity baseEntity;

  @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
  private String name;
}
```

Now when I save a room entity the embedded BaseEntity is null and that is why nothing is audited. According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.4.4/reference/html/#auditing.annotations it should just work like this. How can I fix this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "room")
@Builder
public class room {

...

  @JsonUnwrapped
  @Embedded
  private BaseEntity baseEntity = new BaseEntity();

...
}
```